# jQuery regex, allow more than one dot in filename

Tags: jquery, html, regex, forms

I'm trying to make it possible for the user to upload a file with more than one dot in the file name (eg. "file..jpg", "test.file.jpg" or maybe "file.jpg.jpeg").

I have the following expression which currently only allows one dot (eg. "file.jpg") through `\.`:

```
var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
```

Any advice on how to make this possible?

Complete script:

```
var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
switch (ext) {
    case 'pdf':
    case 'jpg':
    case 'png':
        break;
    default:
        alert('Not allowed file type');
        this.value = '';
};
```

Comment: Is your code above trying to get the file extension of the filename? If so `this.value.split('.').pop()` will do it.

Comment: Ah, yes. My bad. Updated the question with the complete script.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This does the trick, man! You should post this as an answer, and I'll accept it as a solution. I was fooled in the beginning into thinking this didn't solve the problem, but it was only due to case sensitivity issues on the extensions. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code above is simply trying to get the file extension of the filename then you can split the filename to an array by `.` and then use `pop()`. You can also put the valid extensions in an array and use `indexOf()` to check for validity. Try this:

```
var validExt = [ 'pdf', 'jpg', 'png' ];
var ext = this.value.split('.').pop();

if (validExt.indexOf(ext.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
    alert('Not allowed file type');
    this.value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//var files = this.value.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)[1];
var ext = "test.file.jpg".match(/\.([^.]+)$/)[1];
switch (ext) {
    case 'pdf':
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'png':
        alert('file type allowed');
        break;
    default:
        alert('Not allowed file type');
        this.value = '';
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It does indeed allow files with more than one dot in the filename, but it seems that the validation on file type is broken and all file types passes through.